# How to GO PREVIOUS in string with Substring until a SPACE is met. c#

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, substring, intellisense

I have Textbox, on which i need to GO Previous in text string until a space is met 
Like :

> string text = "SELECT * FROM Codes C";

I want to start from "C" and go back until "Codes" is extracted.

Comment: You're not accepting sql in a textbox are you? Please say this is just for your own testing.

Comment: @Yatrix Yes I need it, i am making an Intellisense functional textbox in WPF

Comment: Eh, no one does SQL injection these days. I'm sure you're fine.

Comment: @Yatrix, Yes I am, If you don,t know the answer, then please don,t object on question.

Comment: You're right. I was wrong to point out that you're leaving a massive security hole in your application. I apologize.

Comment: @Yatrix, Don,t Worry, everything is heavily encrypted and safe.

Comment: Hey, it's not my problem. I just try to point out awful decisions to help people. Anyway, best of luck to your employer. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wdsy8fy.aspx) to search from the end. In your case it looks like you want the *second* space from the end. Without any bounds checking, this is:

```
var posOfCodes = text.LastIndexOf(" ", text.LastIndexOf(" ") - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string BeforeLast(string txt)    
{
    var sarr = txt.Split();
    return sarr.Length > 1 ? sarr[sarr.Length - 2] : String.Empty;
}
```